# How to reconstruct a scikit-learn predictor for Gradient Boosting Regressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, prediction, gbm, representation, natural-gradient-boosting

I would like to train my datasets in `scikit-learn` but export the final Gradient Boosting Regressor elsewhere so that I can make predictions directly on another platform.

I am aware that we can obtain the individual decision trees used by the regressor by accessing `regressor.estimators[].tree_`. What I would like to know is how to fit these decision trees together to make the final regression predictor.

Comment: You can directly save the model to disk and load it on the other platform. Why you want to do this complex exercise. Please explain a bit more in detail

Comment: By 'another platform' I mean a software environment other than Python. It is MQL5 used for forex trading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two estimators *i.e. The initial predictor and the sub-estimators*

> **init_estimator**
>
> *The estimator that provides the initial predictions. Set via the init argument or loss.init_estimator.*
> **estimators_**
>
> *ndarray of DecisionTreeRegressor of shape (n_estimators, 1)
>
> The collection of fitted sub-estimators.*

Prediction after the first (*i.e. init*) estimator is controlled by the learning rate.

You can get the prediction as done in the below code -

```py
trees = model.estimators_

x  = x_test.iloc[10,:].values # A sample X to be predicted
y_pred = model.init_.predict(x.reshape(1, -1)) # prediction from init estimator

for tree in trees:
    pred = tree[0].predict(x.reshape(1, -1)) # prediction from sub-estimator

    y_pred = y_pred + model.learning_rate*pred  # Summing with LR
y_pred
```

Comment: Interesting. I will test it out tomorrow. So we just use the initial sample repeatedly without having to worry about deviation from y, ie. the gradient?

Comment: Not initial sample, it's the "x" to be predicted e.g. x_test. Trees are already fitted.

Comment: Great. The figures matched precisely!

Comment: You seem to be knowledgeable in this field. I have some other questions. Could you please take a look? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/87122/how-to-obtain-the-final-values-of-a-decisiontreeregressor-in-scikit-learn     https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/what-quantile-is-used-for-the-initial-dummyregressor-for-gradient-boosting-regre