# What quantile is used for the initial DummyRegressor for Gradient Boosting Regressor in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, loss-function, gbm

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html) of Scikit-Learn Gradient Boosting Regressor:

> init: estimator or ‘zero’, default=None: An estimator object that is used to compute the initial predictions. init has to provide fit and predict. If ‘zero’, the initial raw predictions are set to zero. By default a DummyEstimator is used, predicting either the average target value (for loss=’ls’), or a quantile for the other losses.

So what quantile is used for the DummyRegressor if the loss function is 'huber'? Is it the 50-quantile, ie. median?

I need this information because I am reconstructing the predictor for the Gradient Boosting Regressor for use in another software environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a GBM with Huber loss initializes with the median.  The relevant bit of code is the method `init_estimator` of the loss class, in the file `_gb_losses.py`.  For `HuberLossFunction`:

```py
def init_estimator(self):
    return DummyRegressor(strategy='quantile', quantile=.5)
```

([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/ensemble/_gb_losses.py#L336))

Comment: Thanks. I am somewhat confused. Is it the median of the x's to be tested? Shouldn't it be the median of the y's of the original samples?

Comment: It is indeed the median of the training `y`. See e.g. the documentation for `DummyRegressor`.