# How to obtain the final values of a DecisionTreeRegressor in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, decision-trees

[This page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py) shows the paths in the decision trees in `scikit-learn`. After reaching the leaf nodes of the decision tree, where do we obtain the final resultant value?

Comment: Check in the value attribute i.e. `regressor.tree_.value`

Comment: Alright. Is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For documentation**, *check the Scikit-Learn code at Github i.e. line#535* [[**Link**]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx)

> *value : array of double, shape [node_count, n_outputs, max_n_classes]*
>
> **Contains the constant prediction value of each node.**

You can check the same using this sample code.

- *Identify the leaf nodes*
- *Slice the value attributes for leaf nodes*

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5)
regressor.fit(X, y)

children_left = regressor.tree_.children_left
children_right = regressor.tree_.children_right
leaf_nodes = []
for i in range(n_nodes):
    if children_left[i] == children_right[i]:
        leaf_nodes.append(i)

y_pred =  regressor.predict(X)
all_val = regressor.tree_.value[leaf_nodes,0,0] # Sliced on Leaf nodes

# Check if all the y_pred is from these values
set(y_pred) - set(all_val) # Or, [elem for elem in y_pred if elem not in all_val]
```

Answer (score 0):

The decision depends on the loss function used. If you are using the Mean Square Error you use the within-leaf mean. The fastest way is to use the `.apply()` method and estimate the average of observations that fall in the same leaf.

Comment: Could you show any relevant documentation?